# AngularJs dynamic name for a form inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How do I name a form inside ng-repeat with a dynamic name?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
 <form name="item_details" ng-class="validateForm(item_details)">
   //few form elements
 </form>
</div>
```

I want to name each form dynamically. For example add the $index to the name of the form. How do I achieve it? I tried ng-init on ng-repeat but did not work.

Comment: downvotes make no sense - it is a legitimate question

Comment: i agree that downvotes make no sense.

Comment: yes no reason to down vote, this is a legitimately difficult task that has generated legitimately helpful answers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just do:

```
<form name="item_details{{$index}}" ng-class="validateForm('item_details'+$index)">
```

**EDIT**:

You can use `ng-init` as well, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-init="formName = 'item_details' + $index">
 <form name="{{formName}}" ng-class="validateForm(formName)">
   //few form elements
 </form>
</div>
```

If it's just to apply a class based on validity of the form, then you could apply styling to [automatically added classes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form/#css-classes), such as: `ng-valid`:

```
.ng-valid {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This didnt work. `<form name="item_details{{$index}}" ng-class="validateForm(item_details{{$index}})">`  validateForm method received undefined for form variable input.

Comment: You missed my point. You don't need the `validateFrom` if all you need to do is to style the CSS

Comment: its a complex validation and not css change. Multiple form fields values are validated to enable the submit button.

Comment: with this case, validateForm method does not receive the form controller instance. Instead its input becomes "String" object with form name

Comment: can you please define `validateForm(formName)` this function

Answer (score 2):

You may access the instance of the form by the dynamic name using bracket notation:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
  <form name="item_details{{$index}}" ng-class="validateForm(this['item_details' + $index])">
    //few form elements
  </form>
</div>
```