# AngularJs dynamic name for a form inside ng-repeat for changing array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the code suggested in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513192/angularjs-dynamic-name-for-a-form-inside-ng-repeat) as follows

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-init="formName = 'item_details' + $index">
 <form name="{{formName}}" ng-class="validateForm(formName)">
   //few form elements
 </form>
</div>
```

But my problem is when the array(itemList) values changes form name remains same. I want form name should be updated based on index value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `$index` do use some unique property, may be item has its own `id` property which defines uniqueness of item. So `ng-init` will look like `formName = 'item_details' + item.id"`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-init="formName = 'item_details' + item.id">
 <form name="{{formName}}" ng-class="validateForm(formName)">
   //few form elements
 </form>
</div>
```

---

Even I'm wondering what is need behind you are making each form with unique name? You can have nested forms and `innerForm` will get validated lonely. Thereafter the way validation will handle is, when all `innerForm` gets valid, `outForm` is valid. When any of the `innerForm` is invalid `outerForm` will be invalid in that case.

```
<ng-form ng-repeat="item in itemList" name="outerform">
 <form name="innerForm" ng-class="validateForm(innerForm)">
   //few form elements
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I initialize form name like 
`name="innerForm{{$index}}"` and that worked, even when I delete form name got changes accoedingly.

Comment: @Kartik no, it shouldn't be `$index` it would be the same on removal of item, did you tried what I suggested?

Comment: @Kartik does  my answer helped?

Comment: as per your suggestion I cannot use item.id, as there is no id value associated with it and I cannot change my array object. And yes $index worked bcoz I wanted just the form name as per their index value. If arrat value is modified then form name also modified according to its index value. Thanks